# Is there anyone out there who can guide me to interface my IMU, encoders with ROS. I can not find any tutorial on it

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to make a 3D map of the environment using a 2D laser scanner. For this I have to setup my robot first to get the odometry and orientation and a sonar sensor to measure the height from the ground. So i need to interface some sensors with ROS but i dnt know how

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223912/hi-there,-i-know-the-question-is-dumb-but-is-there-anyone-out-there-who-can-guide-me-to-interface-my-imu,-encoders-with-ros.-i-can-not-find-any-tutorial-on-it./) by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) on 2016-01-12**:
How are these sensors connected to your computer? What kind of robot are you using?

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-12**:
That is what the question is, how should i connect those sensors to computer. Have i to use usb serial communication with every sensor to get its data into computer ? And then after getting into the computer whats the way to get this data into Ros

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-12**:
I have my own quadrotor, i am not using any specific ros robots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It all depends.

Hardware:
Laserscanners can be connected over a serial connection or USB or Ethernet, depending on the type of the scanner, IMUs are often connected over Serial or USB, low level sensors like switches or wheel encoders are often connected to a microcontroller which is connected to the main PC.

Software:
You need ROS-drivers for the Sensors, for some laserscanners and IMUs you can find ROS packages, or you can program them yourself.
Some motorcontrollers have inputs for wheel-encoders.

And now for something completely different:
A IMU alone is not able to measure a position in space, and to assemble a 3D scan from a flying not really known position will not be easy. Why don't you try to generate a 3D scan from a fixed position first.

**Edit:**

for a non flying test: I meant keep the position fixed, but change the orientation of the scanner (tilt it or rotate it), then you don't start with both problems of measuring the orientation and the position at the same time.

Do you know [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) ? This could start you on the software side.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-13**:
this means that i have to get those specific IMUs which are supported by ROS or which has their drivers for ROS. I will be using the SONAR sensor to get the height measurement of the QUAD. how can i guarantee a 3D scan until I have the height measurement.

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-13**:
I think from fixed position, only 2D scan can be guaranteed.

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-13**:
thanku so much the help! actually I was trying to reproduce what is shown in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2UIN-bkGe8&feature=player_detailpage

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-13**:
is it possible that I use arduino to get my sensor values into ROS ?

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2016-03-01**:
Please have a look at the rosserial package and the supporting tutorials.